# Considering the character is not selectable as a mesh, how would I mirror these earrings?

Tags: mirror

Considering the character is not selectable as a mesh, how would I mirror these earrings to the other side of the head/the other ear? (The helixes, stud was just there for reference)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The result that you're trying to achieve is actually very easy to do.

1. Add an empty.
2. Position it to be in the middle of your character's head.
3. Put a mirror modifier on your ring objects.
4. Use that empty as the "mirror object."

[image]